# Bash script to change password in chroot

Tags: bash, shell-script, system-installation, password, lfs

I have build a Linux From Scratch live CD and wrote an installer script for it. There is a step in that script in which I take an username and password from the user and create an user. The installed filesystem is mounted at `/mnt` The username is stored in `$USER` and password in `$PASS`

To create the user, I use

> chroot /mnt useradd $USER -s /bin/bash -m

To change the password, I use

> chroot /mnt echo "$USER:$PASS"|chpasswd

But when I boot into the installed filesystem, I notice that the user has been created, but no password has been assigned. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  Avoids the situation where **chroot /mnt echo "$USER:$PASS"|chpasswd** is failing due to the echo running within the chroot and the chpasswd running *outside* the chroot.

```
echo "$USER:$PASS" >/mnt/foo
chroot /mnt 'chpasswd </foo'
rm /mnt/foo
```

Comment: also worth mentioning is that if `$USER` exists on the host system outside of the `chroot`, then that user's password will have been changed by running the `chpasswd` outside of the `chroot`.  Oh, and, you don't need a temporary file.  `chroot /mnt sh -c "echo '$USER:$PASS' | chpasswd"` will work.  Note well the use of double-quotes around the entire pipeline executed by `sh -c`, and the single-quotes around the variables, this allows the vars to be interpolated.